# PGXN Client for windows?

Tags: postgresql

I need to install this extension for PostgreSQL:

https://github.com/tvondra/quantile

Installation suggests I should use a PGXN client,

But all PGXN clients I looked seems to be targeted for Linux.

Is there a PGXN client I can download to easilly install this extension?

Answer (score 3):

If you already installed python with pip
try to run this command:

```
pip install pgxnclient
```

and use pgxnclient